# get jquery post data in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I hope this is not a stupid question or a duplicate but it seems like everywhere I look there is a different answer and I have not been able to get any of them to work...

With jQuery and PHP, I am able to do the following to send and receive data between the front end and back end ->

```
$.post("logic.php", {
    command: command
}, function(data, status) {
    $("#output").html(data);
}); //jQuery (front-end)


if (isset($_POST['command'])) {
    $command = $_POST['command'];
    if ($command == 'about') {
        echo 'about';
    } else {
        echo 'command not found';
    }
} // PHP (back-end)
```

The communication works and seems rather simple. Now, I am converting to Node.js and am having a very hard time achieving the same affect. I am not getting any errors but it dosen't seem to be communicating at all... I have tried many different things but here is what I have now ->

```
$.post("index.js", {
    command: command
}, function(data, status) {
    out(data); /* out is a function i made that puts the data on the page in a nice format */
}); // jQuery (front-end)


var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
// Javascript back-end
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body) ;
}); // Should log command to the console but nothing at all happens
```

I am very new to node.js but wanted to transition from PHP because I heard about the great AJAX capabilities (which is what my application is based off of)... please help :)

Comment: You need to install the bodyParser middleware in your app.  Learn about how Express works.

Comment: @SLaks He's using that. @OP: You're requesting `index.js`, but you need `$.post("/", ...)`

Comment: You also need to actually run a server and set paths.

Comment: However, I'm not sure what you mean by "node's great AJAX capabilities"... AJAX is done from the client side. node works very different than PHP. For one, while express does support static files, everything else is done by routes; this basically means that `site.com/a/b` from the client's view rarely means "file b in folder a" on the server.

Comment: I am aware that I need the bodyParser, express, and a server running. I have all of that working, I only posted the code for the AJAX part. Should I revise and insert my entire code?

Comment: Did you read my first comment? You need `$.post("/", ...)`, since that's the route you're handling server-side.

Comment: @ChrisG Your solution combined with Meghans is actually working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `bodyParser`, but never use it. You have to add it to the express configuration.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

After this, `req.body` will not longer be `undefined`.

Comment: I added that in but it is giving me an error “body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option”. It still doesn’t work. Do I need something with success and error attributes?

Comment: @MichaelHoefler `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`